# Multiple CSS Stylesheets trouble with Universal Header in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styling

this is my first time asking a question over here, and I am having some trouble with a website I am doing.

I want to have a universal header and footer system so I don't have to redo it on every single page. I am using bootstrap 3 to style my website. I have used bootstrap with no problem before, using HTML only. But now, I have everything in php, mainly a header.php, footer.php, and index.php in this case. I am able to use the include functions to add the header.php and footer.php into my index.php file, but things stop working when I am trying to customize the navbar colors for example. I made a "styles.css" file with my ".navbar-custom" class, but apparently it is not being linked when I call it in my code. Any ideas why it may not be working? Why is the link to /css/styles.css ignored?

I am new using php, and I am teaching myself, this website being a test project.

Here is the code for each file:

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sitio Oficial de MMOBurger</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">       
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://mmoburger.com">MMOBurger</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-targer = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><a href="http://mmoburger.com">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Foro</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tienda</a></li>
                </ul>                       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

footer.php

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<?php
 /* 
 *Website designed and created by Jose Antonio Montes, aka NeoAnthony
 *All rights reserved MMOBurger S.A. 
 */
 include ("header.php");
 ?>

<div class="container">
    <h1>
        Hello World! 
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></div>
    </h1> 
</div>

<?php
include ("footer.php");
?>
```

styles.css

```
//Extra Styles

//NAVBAR COLORS
.navbar-custom {
background-color:#000;
color:#269abc;
border-radius:0;
}
//END NAVBAR COLORS
```

I am expecting at least the background color of the navbar to change to black or any color I input on "background-color". I just get a blank navbar, and curiously, blue text.

Here is a screenshot of how it renders:

[Website navbar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T61D.jpg)

Thanks for your patience! Have a nice day!

Comment: You've commented your CSS incorrectly. A CSS comment starts with `/*` and ends with `*/`. Try removing the comments that start with `//` or replace them with the correct syntax.

Comment: @mikehomme Good catch. Everything else looks fine, so that has gotta be it.

Comment: @mikehomme That was totally it! Thanks for your help! I would have never guessed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mikehomme said in the comments, it was your comments CSS formating that were wrong. It should be like this `/* your comment */`

[See the working example](http://www.bootply.com/gBGfjqgEuu)

The blue text was not from your CSS code but from bootstrap default color text for navbar links.

Comment: That was totally it! Wow, now I feel plain stupid. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome ! don't forget to validate the subject if it's ok for you ;)